# React Native change data displayed in the app according to selected button

Tags: react-native

In the top on my app, I have 3 buttons: Load1, Load2, Add.

Load1 => Load data1 and display content

Load2 => Load data2 and display content

Add => Add data

3 Buttons:

```
class Comp1 extends Component {
    ...
    renderMainPage() {
      switch (this.state.selectedButton) {
        case 'load1':
          return <ListComp status="load1" />;
        case 'closed':
          return <ListComp status="load2" />;
        case 'add':
          return <AddComp status="add" />;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
    ...
    render() {
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
           <Button onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedButton: 'load1' })} > <Text>Load1</Text>
           </Button>
           <Button onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedButton: 'load2' })} > <Text>Load2</Text>
           </Button>
           <Button onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedButton: 'add' })} > <Text>Add</Text>
           </Button>
           {this.renderMainPage()}
        </View>
    }
}
```

Buttons are working just fine and loading the correct content. 
The ListComp:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
}

getData = async () => {
    if (this.props.status === 'load1') {
      await this.props.getLoad1();
    } else if (this.props.status === 'load2') {
      await this.props.getLoad2();
    }
    this.setState({
      myData: this.props.data
    });
};
```

Then the AddComp is just a form Component. It default loads with the "Load1" data. Then, I click on "Load2" it gets the load2 data. Then, I click on "Add" and click back on "Load1". It goes to `this.props.getLoad1()`, but did not update the "myData".

If I keep switching between "Load1" and "Load2", it work just fine.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you press the Add button?

Comment: Did you check whether the componentDidMount especially at the ListComp is running as your intended purposes? with the correct props value? Maybe you could try debugging it with `console.log` at the componentDidMount and look at the `react-native log-android`

Comment: the getData has the correct this.props.status and calls the correct method, but it doesn't update the props.data